# Conectedness in two spaces

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$ be a topological space and $Y$ a closed subset of $X$. Now let $A$ be a subset of $Y$. Is the following true:

> $A$ is connected in $Y$ iff $A$ is connected in $X$.

Comment: Welcome to MSE! What've you tried?

Comment: What do you mean by "connected in"? The usual definition of connectedness is not a relative one. A topological space is either connected or disconnected and this does not depend on any space it is a subspace of.

Comment: @MatthiasKlupsch I suppose he means for the induced topology. What I understand is that he needs to prove the following: $A$ is connected for the topology induced by $Y$ iff $A$ is connected for the topology induced by $X$.

Comment: @MoebiusCorzer Please correct me if I am wrong but these two topologies you describe seem to be identical to me. I mean $U \subseteq A$ is open for the topology induced by $Y$ iff $U = U' \cap A$ for some open subset $U'$ of $Y$. But $U' = U'' \cap X$ for some open subset $U''$ of $X$ as $Y$ is equipped with the topology induced by $X$, hence $U = U'' \cap A$ is open w.r.t. the topology induced by $X$.

Comment: Yes, I also think they are identical but it is not in contradiction with what he has to prove. Actually, it proves it if "connected in" is defined as I think it is.